# If a = b (mod m) and gcd(a,b) = 1, then gcd(a,m) = 1

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm

I can't figure out how to prove this. I know m | (a-b) and I know that there is some integers x and y such that ax + by = 1, however I do not know how to connect these two things to prove the result that the gcd(a,m) = 1. Please help!

Comment: Hint:  suppose $p$, a prime, divides both $a$ and $m$.  show that $p$ divides $b$.

Comment: Note:  the statement you are trying to prove is considerably more elementary than Bezout's Identity...I think it is worth proving it directly, rather than by the use of such a hard result.

Answer (score 5):

Given the assumptions, we can write $b=a+mk$ and $ax+by=1$ for some $k,x,y\in\Bbb Z$. Hence, $$ax+(a+mk)y=1\implies a(x+y)+m(ky)=1$$

Comment: Actually it would be b = a - mk, which just changes the final solution to be a(x+y) + m(-ky) = 1, which still proves that gcd (a,m) = 1. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Actually, since $k$ is an integer, it doesn't matter (i.e. we could just use $-k$). So if you want to write $b=a-mk$ that is fine, but writing $b=a+mk$ is also fine.

Answer (score 0):

(Following the comments on the OP)

We want to show that any $d$ that divides both $a$ and $m$ must divide $1$.

We know that $b=a+km$. Therefore, if $d|a$ and $d|m$, then also we have $d|b$. But, if $d$ divides both $a$ and $b$, then it divides $(a,b)$, which is $1$.